# ndk-gdb cannot find gdb.setup but it is there under x86

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, ndk-gdb

Cocos2d-x 3.7.1 + ndk r10e project on Mac trying to debug in Eclipse.  Days pass and the errors keep coming...

I can build and run using cocos compile and cocos run with -p android -m debug --ndk-mode NDK_DEBUG=1 from the terminal in proj.android.

My app runs Ok (eventually) on my x86 emulator no problem.

Typing 'ndk-gdb' in the terminal from ./proj.android and I get the error

> ERROR: Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/

**BUT** the file gdb.setup (and gdbserver & libcocos2dcpp.so) can be seen in ./proj.android/libs/x86 !?

My AndroidManifest.xml includes android:debuggable="true"

My jni/Application.mk includes APP_ABI := x86 (only)

If anyone can tell me how I can diagnose or fix this problem then I guess I owe them a beer (in Yorkshire btw)

**UPDATE:**  I have tried running up GDB using the --verbose flag.  The output shows

> Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
>
> Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi

Guess I need to change to settings/init file somewhere??

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. It seems something changed in recent version of Android Build tools.

The trick is:

```
ERROR: Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/
```

It expects gdb.setup is in the directory **libs** but **NOT** **libs/armeabi**

so the simple workground is to copy gdb.setup and gdbserver from "libs/cpu" to "libs" and it works like a magic!

Answer (score 0):

- This is a bug caused by adb from android sdk.[Issue 191085:  ndk-gdb issue - Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/ (even though it's there)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191085)
- Currently previewl channel's adb whose version is 1.0.35 still has the same problem.
- Without revert adb to 1.0.31.A simple workaround would be modify ndk-gdb a little: change the line `if [ $? = 0 ]; then` which is below `adb_var_shell BCFILES run-as $PACKAGE_NAME /system/bin/sh -c "ls lib/*.bc"` to `if [ $? = 1 ]; then`