# ndk-gdb unable to find gdb.setup

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, ndk-gdb

I am trying to use ndk-gdb to debug my native android project. When I run the command ndk-gdb I get the error

```
 Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/
```

Explanation

- Running MacOSX, ndk r10e; Using ndk sample San Angeles
- Followed steps here to setup native debugging https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-gdb.html
- Basically I set android:debuggable="true", APP_OPTIM := debug and built native using ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 (these 3 setting may be superfluous, but just in case)
- Used ant debug, adb install to install; Ran app and app runs fine
- Running ndk-gdb --verbose produces

  `ndk-gdb --verbose`

  Android NDK installation path:

  ```
    /Users/hanantha/Documents/Dev/android-ndk-r10e
  ```

  Using default adb command:

  ```
   /Users/hanantha/Documents/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
  ```

  ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

  ```
   Revision eac51f2bb6a8-android
  ```

  Using ADB flags:

  Using JDB command:

  ```
  /usr/bin/jdb
  ```

  Using auto-detected project path: .

  Found package name: `com.example.SanAngeles`

  ABIs targetted by application: arm64-v8a armeabi armeabi-v7a armeabi-v7a mips mips64 x86 x86_64

  Device API Level: 19

  Device CPU ABIs: x86

  Compatible device ABI:

  Using gdb setup init:

  ```
   ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
  ```

  Using toolchain prefix:

  ```
   /Users/hanantha/Documents/Dev/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-
  ```

  Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi

  Found debuggable flag: `true`

  ERROR:

  ```
      Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/
     This usually means you modified your AndroidManifest.xml to set
     the android:debuggable flag to 'true' but did not rebuild the
     native binaries. Please call 'ndk-build' to do so,
     *then* re-install to the device!
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just answered in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32972182/1617066

I ran into the same problem. It seems something changed in recent version of Android Build tools.

The trick is:

```
ERROR: Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/
```

It expects gdb.setup is in the directory **libs** but **NOT** **libs/armeabi**

so the simple workground is to copy gdb.setup and gdbserver from "libs/cpu" to "libs" and it works like a magic!

Comment: Filed a bug with Google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188885

Answer (score 0):

- This is a bug from adb. [Issue 191085:   ndk-gdb issue - Could not find gdb.setup under ./libs/ (even though it's there)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191085)
- I recommend to [modify ndk-gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437554/ndk-gdb-cannot-find-gdb-setup-but-it-is-there-under-x86/36196597#36196597) rather than copy `gdb.setup` to `libs` every time you debug a new project: